# Android: Display element of array with time delay?

Tags: java, android, arrays, timer, android-handler

While working on a larger project, I wanted to display all elements of a String array with a time delay (so as to be readable by the user).

In my example, I have a `StringBuilder text` that is split on tabs and stored in `String[] words`.

My initial idea was to use something like:

```
String[] words = text.toString().split("\t");
for (String word : words) {
    textView.setText(word);
    SystemClock.sleep(2000);
}
```

However, this blocks the UI thread and thus only shows the last value. After reading up abit more, I came up with this solution (which works):

```
final String[] words = text.toString().split("\t");
final Handler handler = new Handler();

handler.post(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        textView.setText(words[i]);
        i++;
        if(i < words.length) {
            handler.postDelayed(this, TIME_DELAY_MS);
        }
    }
});
```

However, this requires me to have `i` as a private variable of the class (declaring it in the same scope as the handler forces it to be final, which it can't be in order to go through the array).

Having a private variable of the class just for this purpose seems very inelegant - is there any better way of doing this that I missed?

Comment: You can use a temporary final variable that is a copy of "i" if you wanna do in another way!

Comment: If you know RxJava: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/timer.html

Comment: @SiloéBezerraBispo I'm not sure I understand how you mean? Would that save me from having `i` as a class variable?

Answer (score 5):

**Try this** code :

```
public class test extends Activity {

private TextView textView;
private int i = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    set();
}
private void set(){

    final String text ="A n d r o i d P r o g r a m m i n g";
    final String[] words = text.toString().split(" ");
    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    handler.post(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            textView.setText(""+words[i]);
            i++;
            if(i < words.length) {
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        }
    });
}}
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, that's exactly the same as the second idea mentioned in the question, apart from the unnecessary `""+` when setting the textView's text (`words[i]` is already a String).